# How to implement autocomplete feature in Javascript with external JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, autocomplete

I need to create an autocomplete feature which uses data from an external JSON I have.
Here is my HTML

```
<div>
 <input id="autoComplete">
</div>
```

Here is my data.json which will be stored in the root folder.

```
[
 {
   "en": "vague",
   "ml": "avyakta"
 },
 {
   "en": "plethora",
   "ml": "atika"
 },
 {
   "en": "army",
   "ml": "pada"
 },
 {
   "en": "alter",
   "ml": "maru"
 },
 {
   "en": "totality",
   "ml": "motta"
 }
]
```

My target is to trigger an autocomplete feature when the input length is greater than 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=autocomplete+from+json+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8gyj0hxw/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI for this. Add jQuery UI & then use that code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#autoComplete').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "list.json",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: request,
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return (`${item.en} : ${item.ml}`)
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it out